# Putting swf back into an AIR package?

Tags: flash, air

Gidday

I'm using Pro CS6 to make an AIR app.

I'd like to use TelemetryEasy to turn on advanced telemetry in it so I can use Scout.

The maker of TelemetryEasy says you have to run it against the swf prior to packaging the AIR app.

I don't want to hit him up with any more than the two questions I've asked him, so I was wondering if anyone here knows how to do that if you are compiling with Flash Pro?

I can extract the swf with 7zip, and then drag it onto TelemetryEasy, which says it's updated it, but then how do I get the swf back in the AIR package?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An .air file is just a .zip file with a different extension (the same is true for .ipa and .apk files for iOS and Android devices).

So:

1) Rename your file from myApp.air to myApp.zip (to make it easier for your zip software to recognise it).

2) Open the zip file and extract the swf.

3) Update the swf and add it back into zip file.

4) Rename myApp.zip back to myApp.air and you should be good to go.

Comment: OK - step 3 is where I get stuck.

Comment: OK - step 3 is where I get stuck. I open the zip file in 7zip (so I can see all the files). I then drag the updated swf from windows into the 7zip window, but it says 'Not Implemented". Doing it another way - extract all the files, update the swf, recreate zip, name change to .air, then attempt install - it tells me the installer is damaged. I should mention that there is an error when unzipping - something about 'unsupported compression method for the hash file'

Comment: I use WinZip and have had no problems - have you tried different archive software?

Comment: Yeah - I tried 7zip and WinZip - both gave crc errors. I'll try some others. I'm guessing there's some sort of protection that prevents you doing this with AIR files now?

Comment: You could try this app for adding telemetry; might give different results: http://renaun.com/blog/2012/12/enable-advanced-telemetry-on-flex-or-old-swfs-with-swf-scount-enabler/

Answer (score 1):

I tried all sort of zipping, the only way that doesn't give an invalid package, is using WinZip, but not re-zipping the entire package, you just have to:

- open apk (renamed zip) win WinZip
- drag the modified swf into assets
- close WinZip and save

In this case, the application install process will start. But it still gives "Application not installed".